# Heavy CPU Usage for Interrupt

Tags: windows-xp, cpu-usage, process-explorer, interrupts

As a follow-up to the question

> [Why can't my computer speed up again after closing large applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/388200/why-cant-my-computer-speed-up-again-after-closing-large-applications)

… I used Process Explorer to check my PC.

I found that there's an average 30-40% of CPU being used by `Interrupt`. Is that normal?

If it is not normal, could you suggest any method to check for the cause?
**EDIT**: Although this question was tagged as an exact duplicate of another question, I found the solution on the other question is not working in Windows xp. Installation of Windows performance toolkit on my Windows xp machine doesn't work to make the command "xperf" working in command prompt. If it is possible, please help to provide some other method to find the cause.

I've execute the DPC Latency Checker and it suggest a broken driver. I checked in the Device Manager and everything seems fine. No Yellow "!" symbol.
[image]

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/202254/how-do-i-get-to-the-root-cause-of-high-deferred-procedure-calls

Comment: IMO, only if Interrupt equals to Deferred Procedure Call and Windows Xp equals to Windows 7/vista, this can be treat as exact duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's definitely not normal. The most likely cause of such a higher interrupt level is broken hardware or a broken driver. It can also be caused by a disk being in PIO mode rather than DMA mode. Sometimes it can even be a BIOS bug.